# Facebook Icon is not clickable in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, facebook, internet-explorer-8

I am unable to click the `FaceBook` Icon in `Internet Explorer - 8 and 9`.

#### **[Here is my JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6ctA/)** .

It is working fine in `IE(7)` and FF.

### Mark Up

```
<div style="z-index: 1000;" class="footershareBox">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Share</strong> </li>
        <li><span id="ctl00_ucFootercontainer_ucSocialShareIcons_lbFB"><a type="icon_link"
            name="fb_share" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fdish.amplio.biz%2FUSASatellite&amp;t=DISH%20Retailer%20USA%20Satellite%2C%20Inc.%2C%20Denver%2C%20CO&amp;src=sp"
            style="text-decoration: none;"><span class="FBConnectButton_Simple"><span class="FBConnectButton_Text_Simple">
                Facebook</span></span></a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share"></script></span>
        </li>
        <li><a target="_blank" id="ctl00_ucFootercontainer_ucSocialShareIcons_aLinkedin"
            href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=http://dish.amplio.biz/USASatellite&amp;title=DISH+Retailer+Dish+User%2c+Denver%2c+CO&amp;summary=Save+with+DISH.+Why+would+you+ever+pay+more+for+TV%3f&amp;source=DISHNetwork">
            <img alt="" src="/Images/linkedin_share.gif" id="imgLinkedIn">LinkedIn</a> </li>
        <li><a target="_blank" id="ctl00_ucFootercontainer_ucSocialShareIcons_aTwitter" href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http://dish.amplio.biz/USASatellite&amp;text=DISH+Retailer+Dish+User%2c+Denver%2c+CO - Save+with+DISH.+Why+would+you+ever+pay+more+for+TV%3f&amp;related=dish">
            <img alt="" src="/Images/twitter_share.gif" id="imgTwitter">Twitter</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Guest not only 8 but it is not even working in IE 9

Comment: So does not work in IE 8 but works fine in IE 8? awww he fixed it :(

Comment: @naim Do you want +1 and accept or 50 bounty with +1 and accept ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add..

```
display:block;
```

in you span style tag...

Edit [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6ctA/3/)